# How to use my SurfaceView with main.xml on Android?

Tags: android, xml, surfaceview

In the main class of my project, I have

```
public class MyClass extends Activity{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mySurfaceView = new MySurfaceView(this);
        setContentView(mySurfaceView); 
        ...
    }

    class MySurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable{
       ...
    }
}
```

I want to add buttons and wheels to this program, which I have in a separate mini-program right now with a main.xml file. I know that to access that, I have to have the line **setContentView(R.layout.main)**, but then, I lose access to my SurfaceView. How do I make it so that I have both? I saw something online about adding a few lines with a FrameLayout but I can't figure out where, and I've tried sticking it in various places in my main.xml but it just causes my entire program to break..

Currently my main.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
 <Button android:id="@+id/selectButton"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:text="Select Time Interval"
android:onClick="selfDestruct"
/>
<Button android:id="@+id/finishButton"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:text="Done"
android:visibility="gone"
android:onClick="selfDestruct"
/>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top|left"
    android:paddingLeft="12dp"
    android:paddingRight="12dp"
    >
    <kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView android:id="@+id/startHour"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="43dp"/>
    <kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView android:id="@+id/startMins"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
        <kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView android:id="@+id/startAmpm"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        <TextView android:id="@+id/theWordTo"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="   to   "/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView android:id="@+id/endHour"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="43dp"
        />
    <kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView android:id="@+id/endMins"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
        <kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView android:id="@+id/endAmpm"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you want to use [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html). Change your main.xml to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<kankan.current.app.MyClass.MySurfaceView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/surfaceView" />

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
 <Button android:id="@+id/selectButton"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:text="Select Time Interval"
android:onClick="selfDestruct"
/>
<Button android:id="@+id/finishButton"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:text="Done"
android:visibility="gone"
android:onClick="selfDestruct"
/>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top|left"
    android:paddingLeft="12dp"
    android:paddingRight="12dp"
    >
    <kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView android:id="@+id/startHour"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="43dp"/>
    <kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView android:id="@+id/startMins"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
        <kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView android:id="@+id/startAmpm"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        <TextView android:id="@+id/theWordTo"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="   to   "/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView android:id="@+id/endHour"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="43dp"
        />
    <kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView android:id="@+id/endMins"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
        <kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView android:id="@+id/endAmpm"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Then in in the activity:

```
public class MyClass extends Activity{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main); 
        mySurfaceView = (MySurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
    }

    class MySurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable{
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I almost spent two & a half days thinking on how'd I do this & with correct keywords in google search I landed here! Thank you very much sir.

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly possible to add your SurfaceView to the layout at run time (in the `onCreate()` method for instance), but it would probably be far simpler to add it in the XML layout.

For simplicity's sake, I would first define MySurfaceView in its own file, instead of in the same file as your MyClass Activity.  Make sure you include a constructor of the form `MySurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)` so that the view can be inflated properly. Then simply insert the following into your XML layout wherever you want.

```
<com.example.package.MySurfaceView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Where the first line is the path to MySurfaceView (`com.example.package` is the package name, and `MySurfaceView` is the file in which you have defined the custom view).