# creating buttons in main activity while drawing in custom surfaceView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, surfaceview

In my MainActivity i want to handle my Buttons and in my GameSurfaceView i want to handle drawing stuff, but I can't see the buttons on my GameSurfaceView why is that? 
My Gameloop Class handles onDraw calls.
When i set my ContentView to my MainActivity, I don't see my drawings and when i set the ContentView to my GameSurfaceView, i see the drawings but i can't see my buttons.

How do I implement the GameSufaceView to my MainActivity? Please help me.
Here is the short form of my Code:

This is my MainActivity
[edit: i shortened the extract]

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button button1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        }
    });

    setContentView(new GameSurfaceView(this));
    }
}
```

this is my custom SurfaceView

```
public class GameSurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

private Context context;

public GameSurfaceView(Context context){
    super(context);
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    this.context = context;
    setFocusable(true);
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    canvas.drawRect(60, 60, 100, 100, p);
}
```

And here is the xml File from the MainActivity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btn1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[edit]
After another day of searching I found a problem something similiar to mine:
[[How to use my SurfaceView with main.xml on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921135/how-to-use-my-surfaceview-with-main-xml-on-android][1])

But I can still not see the buttons i defined on my MainActivity, i just see a black screen and the rectangle i am drawing:

i added this to my MainActivity `gameSurfaceView = (GameSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.gameSurfaceView);` and deleted `setContentView(new GameSurfaceView(this));`
I added to my xml file this code:

```
<com.example.joschi.tryout.GameSurfaceView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/gameSurfaceView"
    />
```

I am still not able to see the button I defined, why is this? Can someone help me?

Comment: Don't override `onDraw()` in a SurfaceView. The Surface part of SurfaceView is a separate layer; `onDraw()` is drawing on the View part, which should just be a transparent hole (only needed for layout). If you want to draw on a View, create a custom View, and avoid the Surface overhead -- http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html

Comment: ok, thanks for the advice

Comment: This is the same I problem I faced, you can solve this programatically is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved my problem.

I need to define the Button bevore the gameSurfaceView, in the xml file, otherwise the gameSurfaceView is "over" the button and that's the reason I can't see it.